# Why does Android M's permission manager show Location?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

One of my apps has these permissions listed in the manifest:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />`

The permission manager shows Contacts (to be expected), but also Location:

[image]

Simple question: why would the permission manager show the Location permission?

My suspicion was that ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION might require the location permission but denying the permission has no impact on the activity recognition functionality of the app (as far as I can tell).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546197/android-studio-add-unwanted-permission-after-running-application-on-real-device/30546670#30546670

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you. Interestingly enough the function doesn't see to be impacted. I guess they handle the missing permission gracefully.

Comment: Either that, or the pieces of Play Services and other libraries that you are using aren't taking advantage of the permission. If you are using Android Studio and are not doing so already, on the Play Services side, use the more granular dependencies rather than the "kitchen sink" dependency.

Comment: I'm indeed using compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0' and yes that should have given me the answer but sometimes you overlook the obvious.