# Google Play Services enforces permissions

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-permissions

For some reason when adding Google Play Services (Location services only) to an Android skeleton project (default blank activity project) the "Modify to SD card" permission is automatically added, I have no need for that and would like to remove that permission, is this a bug in Play Services or the expected behavior ?

Just to be clear, all I added to the `build.gradle` file is the following line:

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0'

And this is the result:
[image: App permission]

Comment: It is possible permissions can come with dependencies.

Comment: The question is, why does location services require SD card access and can I do something about it?

Comment: And another: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30809815/why-does-play-services-location-need-the-android-permission-write-external-stora