# PlayServices ads library 7.5.0 need WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

In our build.gradle we updated the play-services ads library from 6.5.87 to 7.5.0

```
compile com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0
```

After upgrading we see a new permission in our merged AndroidManifest.xml (placed in /build/intermediates/manifests/full/release/)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Regarding the log of the ManifestMerger this permission is added by play-services-ads:

```
ADDED from com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0:30:9
    android:theme
ADDED from com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0:31:13
    android:name
ADDED from com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0:30:19
    uses-permission#android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

In the official documentation, we do not see any hint that this permission is needed. Only the following permissions are documented:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

(https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/android/quick-start#modifying_the_android_manifest)

Is there any official information, why this new permission was added? Or is this a bug?

Currently we have trouble to explain our users, why we need this new permission.

**EDIT: Wrong alarm!**
I was misinterpreting the manifest-merger-result.txt. 
The new permission was not added by the play-services-**ads** dependency, but we also added the play-services-**location** dependency. The play-services-**location** has a reference to play-services-**maps**, which needs this permission for caching the tiles.

The correct interpretation of the manifest-merger-result.txt is:

```
uses-permission#android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
ADDED from com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.5.0:22:5
```

The play-services-maps automatically add this "missing" permission, if the lib was added. It would be nice to know, if it is a good idea to remove this map-permissions, if we do not use the Map-API. Because we are only using the Location-API.

Comment: How did you get those "ADDED" logs? all my apps use the `play-services-ads` module and I do not have `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission added.

Comment: I simply watched at the manifest-merger-release-report.txt in /app/build/outputs/logs

Comment: Jared: https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/25/hey-where-did-these-permissions-come-from.html

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski ? I just checked my APKs on Google play. They do not require `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. In fact, why don't you just check your device for the permissions?

Comment: @JaredBurrows Do you use play services 7.5.0? And what android version has your device? < 4.4?

Comment: @Christopher Yes. 1) Check your phone's application manager(installing) 2) Check your google play publisher account(click on the APK in the console) 3) Check the APK manifest itself(decompile). My device is 5.1. It should not matter.

Comment: Post your `build.gradle`.

Comment: WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is not needed on devices >= KitKat. Which parts of my build.gradle are you especially interested?

Comment: you can use complie 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0'

Comment: I use compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0'. But this lib has a depedency to com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.5.0. see gradle dependencies

Comment: `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0'` is your problem. This is a duplicate question.

Comment: And here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30809815/why-does-play-services-location-need-the-android-permission-write-external-stora

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed as part of [Google Play services 8.3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/releases#november_5_2015) - the Maps API (which location relies on) no longer requires the storage permission and no longer adds it via manifest merger.