# Android Wear new (unwanted) permissions

Tags: permissions, google-play, android-manifest, wear-os

I recently switched from API 21 to 23 to create Android Wear watch faces.
In the interest of brevity I will not comment on the excruciating process. (1)

As I was uploading to Google Play I noticed that the new API has added, without my consent, 4 new rights:

```
    Required permissions 6 permissions (4 added)
=>    android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
=>    android.permission.INTERNET
    android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
=>    com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE
    com.google.android.permission.PROVIDE_BACKGROUND
=>    com.mycompany.mypackage.permission.C2D_MESSAGE
```

I double checked the manifest which contain my "usual"

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.permission.PROVIDE_BACKGROUND" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

How (the heck) do I get rid of these?
(1) Rarely an API made me want to punch someone square in the face so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra permissions are probably being added by some part of Google Play Services - and which probably doesn't need them for what you're doing.

Solution #1 is to only use the pieces of Google Play Services that you actually need. In your Wear module's `build.gradle` file, you might have an entry that looks like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile com.google.android.gms:play-service:8.4.0
}
```

However, that will bring in the **entire** Play Services library - which requires a number of extra permissions. It might well be that all you need is this:

```
    compile com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.4.0
```

...or perhaps other specific modules. But the point is, don't include more than you need.

If you've pared the `dependencies` back as far as you can, and you're still getting extra permissions in your merged manifest, then you may need Solution #2 - which I described in detail in a different answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31017339/252080

Make sure you read all the way to the bottom, because there are some important caveats.

Comment: play-services-wearable:x.y.x was the culprit indeed. Got rid of it. Cut the APK size in half btw. thx.