# Setting Android Wear permissions in App with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest, wear-os

All:

I got one of those Android Privacy Policy notifications for an Android watch face I wrote. I wrote it in Android Studio, and it has the following permissions:

```
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS
android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE
```

I really don't need all of those. I really think I only need the WAKE_LOCK and I think one other one. It shouldn't use any sort of writing, accessing networks, or any of that other stuff.

But the odd thing is, I can't find anywhere in my app where these permissions are located. This is my Wear manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

<!-- Required to act as a custom watch face. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.permission.PROVIDE_BACKGROUND" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault" >
    <service
        android:name=".MorseWatchFace"
        android:label="@string/my_digital_name"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.service.wallpaper"
            android:resource="@xml/watch_face" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.wearable.watchface.preview"
            android:resource="@drawable/preview_digital" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.wearable.watchface.preview_circular"
            android:resource="@drawable/preview_digital_circular" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />

            <category android:name="com.google.android.wearable.watchface.category.WATCH_FACE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

And this is my Mobile manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="monte.morsewatch">

<application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

</application>
```

I know I'm missing something. The email said I had until January 30th to fix it, but I am unsure what I need to change to fix it.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based from this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/wear-permissions.html), the user must now grant permissions to Wear apps separately from the handset versions of the apps. *Previously, when a user installed a Wear app, it automatically inherited the set of permissions that the user had granted to the handset version of the app.* To declare that your app needs a permission, you're right in putting a [`<uses-permission>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html) element in your [app manifest](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html), as a child of the top-level [`<manifest>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html) element.

This [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37402213/5832311) might also help on how to remove unwanted permissions in your app.

> The extra permissions are probably being added by some part of Google
>   Play Services - and which probably doesn't need them for what you're
>   doing.
>
> Solution #1 is to only use the pieces of Google Play Services that you
>   actually need. In your Wear module's `build.gradle` file, you might
>   have an entry that looks like this:
>
> ```
> dependencies {
>     compile com.google.android.gms:play-service:8.4.0
> }
> ```
>
> However, that will bring in the **entire** Play Services library -
>   which requires a number of extra permissions. It might well be that
>   all you need is this:
>
> ```
>     compile com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.4.0
> ```
>
> ...or perhaps other specific modules. But the point is, don't include
>   more than you need.
>
> If you've pared the `dependencies` back as far as you can, and you're
>   still getting extra permissions in your merged manifest, then you may
>   need Solution #2 - which I described in detail in a different answer:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/31017339/252080

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I'll check that out. Meanwhile, here is the relevant part of my Gradle build for the wear module: 
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.1.0'
}
It seems like I need the first line or my project won't compile.

Comment: Marking as answered, For now this seems to have solved my problem. If it crops up again, I will make a note.