# Wrong permissions at Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

Permissions at my app's Google Play page are wrong. Here is my Manifest (just the permissions)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Here is the full file [AndroidManifest.xml](https://github.com/indywidualny/fNotifier/blob/9337155f7bc5fb1d2977db7fee57d0bc96c2f751/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml)

There is nothing more. Now please take a look at the list below my app description at Google Play. It's obviously wrong.

[image: permissions by Google Play]

I tried do contact Google Play support but they told me nothing.

> At this time, we’re unable to provide technical support for app
>   development-related questions. We’re happy to help with any questions
>   related to publishing apps and managing your apps using the Google
>   Play Developer Console (http://play.google.com/apps/publish).

So now i don't have a clue what to do to make the list right. Did anyone have a similar problem? Every time during app update Google Play tells me that new permissions are required. But a device can see the permissions correctly. They are declared correctly at Manifest. What should I do?

Comment: are you sure you dont have any 3rd party libraries compiled with your app?

Comment: See [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/25/hey-where-did-these-permissions-come-from.html) and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30546670/115145) for more on what tyczj is referring to. In short, libraries that you add to your project, like Play Services, can contribute `<uses-permission>` elements to your app's manifest.

Comment: Well. I use appcompat-v7:22.1.1, support-v4:22.1.1 and saxrssreader which the only permission is INTERNET. (https://github.com/indywidualny/fNotifier/blob/9337155f7bc5fb1d2977db7fee57d0bc96c2f751/saxrssreader/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml) The strange thing is that even the phone during normal installation (outside Google Play) don't show access to files. Only reading phone state (strange because I don't use it) and my declared permissions. Google Play somehow shows more permissions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out what's wrong.

```
getSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "_preferences", Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
```

Android Studio adds access to files because I'm using multi process shared preferences and I'm writing to them somewhere (available since API 11).

Force removing the permission by

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="remove" />
```

in the app's Manifest breaks writing to Shared Prefs. So it's really needed and auto-added by Android Studio.

The second one, `READ_PHONE_STATE` is because of the saxrssreader library. When the library's min SDK is lower than the app's min SDK, the permission is added during build. I simply changed the library's minimum SDK to the number my app is using and the permission is gone.

That was a tricky one but everything is clear now.

Comment: Useful to state you need this in your manifest `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`