# App permissions different on web and phone

Tags: android, google-play

Here's the two different Permissions on web vs play store.

[Web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0rBJ.png)

[App Store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLAME.jpg)

- Ive looked at the build/intermediate.manifests folder. There's no EXTERNAL_STORAGE in the Manifest

  - Same for the outputs/logs/manifest-merger files.

BNelow is the merged manifest

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
> <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE"
> ```
>
> />
>
> ```
> <permission
>     android:name="com.formulaone.production.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
>     android:protectionLevel="signature" />
>
> <uses-permission android:name="com.formulaone.production.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
> <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
> ```

Is there any reason why this is different on web s app?

edit : [Wrong permissions at Google Play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057523/wrong-permissions-at-google-play)

The app does use shared prefs, does that add the external_storage permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Permission Request depends on many factors. Like if you're sending some data which requires storage permission, then you need to add `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission

Also, the permissions on Web and Android varies

I think you are using wrong Android permissions

[Here's](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview) a quick guide for Android Permissions

Comment: The app does **not** need the EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.
So it is not added to the manifest and is not present in the merged manifest either.

BUt ofr some reason, when you view the app on the play store on your laptop broswer, it says the app has a storage permission.

Comment: Then the reason might be that any of your permissions is using `Storage Permission` permission.
The detailed info is given [here](https://medium.com/glucosio-project/how-libraries-can-silently-add-permissions-to-your-android-app-620911d7de6c)

Comment: I did have a read of the article.
I;ve triple checked the build logs, and the merged apk file, there is no mention of storage in ANY file.

Comment: Could you please share the Manifest file?

Comment: Android manifest : https://gist.github.com/AldrichMascarenhas/5c656b0a696b010f4f264303aa8c2903

Comment: Merged manifest (from build/output) https://gist.github.com/AldrichMascarenhas/974d592beca19de6cff6db2e7f69b565