# Where do these required permissions come from?

Tags: android, android-permissions

I created and published an Android (incl. Android Wear support) app and set these permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

However, displaying the permissions in Google Play, these show up:

```
android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE maxSdkVersion=18
android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS
android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

Where are they coming from? Can I get rid of them anyhow?

Comment: from libraries and modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where are they coming from?

[They are coming from libraries that you are using in your project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31972082/where-do-these-required-permissions-come-from), most likely.

> Can I get rid of them anyhow?

Principally, by stopping using those libraries. You can use the manifest merger report to help identify where the specific permissions are coming from.

That roster seems like it might be tied to the Play Services SDK, in which case you might also [try using a more focused portion of that SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546197/android-studio-add-unwanted-permission-after-running-application-on-real-device).

Comment: In this particular case, the wearable part of the Google Play API was sufficient:
`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:7.5.0'`
instead of 
`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'`