# Issues with installing app - provider already used

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-6.0-marshmallow

I created an Android app using Ionic. I am getting an error message while trying to install the update. The exact error message I get is:

> "Can't install because provider name
>   com.google.android.gms.measurement.google_measurement_service is
>   already used by com.lge.wernicke.nlp"

My app uses the [ngCordova google analytics plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/googleAnalytics/), so I'm guessing that's where this service is coming from (I don't see the service in the manifest directly). The error only seems to exist on LG devices (and only those with Marshmallow). I tried to search for the com.lge.wernicke.nlp package to get some idea of what that is and what it's used for, but I can't find anything helpful.

Not sure how to resolve this issue.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33366846/what-is-appmeasurementservice-and-why-does-android-studio-add-this-service-to-my and see if it helps (or any of the links there do).

Comment: I had the same problem when i got old app and i didn't have `applicationId` in `defaultConfig` ( but have "com.example.applicationId" in the manifest itself) ... i'm not sure if it apply to cordova but if you can modify the build.gradle then maybe it would fix the problem