# Migrated to Android Studio - now my app requests additional permissions

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, android-permissions

I just migrated an app from Eclipse to Android Studio. I tried exporting a signed APK and uploaded it to Google Play just to check that everything was working.

That's when I noticed that my app now requests two additional permissions except the ones that I have declared in my manifest! The two permissions are `android.permission.WAKE_LOCK` and `com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE`.

What's going on here? I haven't changed any code since the last time I uploaded the app, and the manifest doesn't declare these permissions. I'm guessing some Google component is responsible for this, but why did this happen because I migrated to Android Studio? Can I turn off these permissions?

I'm using Google Play Services and Google AdMob, but I've been doing that for a long time without these permissions...

*manifest.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.app"
      android:versionCode="70"
      android:versionName="7.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />

    <uses-sdk 
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <application android:name="com.example.app.MyApplication"
                 android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_icon" 
                 android:label="@string/app_name" 
                 android:allowBackup="true"
                 android:uiOptions="none">

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


        <activity android:name="com.example.app.MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme.App"
                  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >

                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity           
            android:name="com.example.app.OtherActivity"
            android:label="@string/otherActivityTitle"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme.App"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.app.MainActivity" >

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.app.MainActivity" />                                 
        </activity>                     

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.PreferencesActivity"
            android:label="@string/prefsTitle" >            
        </activity>                     

        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />


    </application>
</manifest>
```

Here's a screenshot of the APK built using Android Studio:

[image]

I couldn't change the language to english, but it basically says it's now supporting 22 less devices, requires 2 new permissions and uses OpenGL 2.0+ instead of 1.0+.

Here's a screenshot of the same APK built using Eclipse:

[image]

Comment: show you manifest file

Comment: See my edit. It's definitely an Android Studio issue, I just tried building my APK with Eclipse and uploading it to Google Dev console - no extra permissions needed...

Comment: What does "my app now requests" mean? What text? Where it is shown? When?

Comment: When I upload the APK to Google Developer Console, in the box where it shows you the file size and version and you can enter "What's new in this version". Right before you press "Publish to production". That's where it says "7 permissions, 2 new".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more searching I found this thread on Stackoverflow: [Android Studio adds unwanted permission after running application on real device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546197/android-studio-adds-unwanted-permission-after-running-application-on-real-device).

One of the answers there (not the accepted one) solved my issues. It seems that the Android Studio import process added this dependency to my `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

After changing it to

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0' // Needed for API Availability test
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
```

the APK no longer requests the unwanted permissions, it targets the same devices as before and uses the same OpenGL version as before - i.e. everything is back the way it was with Eclipse! Except now the file size of the APK is 1 MB smaller as an added bonus!

For people coming here in the future, you might want to investigate what Google Play Services version numbers you should use at [Gradle, please](http://gradleplease.appspot.com/) and/or [Setting up Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup).

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me too. in my case, I only needed the 2nd line (since it has admob) for this one particular app.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
android:targetSdkVersion="22"
```

Comment: I removed the `targetSdkVersion` from the manifest and instead changed it in `build.gradle` to make sure they're not colliding or anything, but it makes no difference. I have `targetSdkVersion="23"` and the build target set to API 23 in Eclipse as well.