# App is asking for permission i have not added in manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

When I install the apk generated in a device, it asked to accept WAKE_LOCK permission, but it is not added in the manifest.

My manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.myapp.mydomain.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<permission
    android:name="com.myapp.mydomain.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<permission
    android:name="com.myapp.mydomain.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

I do not understand, if it is not added how can be asked? How can I know which lib is trying to access this permission?

Comment: have you add Google analytics in your app

Comment: no matter which lib is using it, if Your app as a whole is needing it, then add it.

Comment: Are you using Marsh-mellow device?

Comment: and You should read trough the README file in Your used libs, usually it is declared which permissions are needed (or it should be declared)...

Comment: @ShoebSiddique Yes I am using Marshmallow to test it.

Comment: @Pitty Nope, i am not using google analytics.

Comment: Ok but I am sure you are using some how library which needs WAKE LOCK  permission to run. check for that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546197/android-studio-adds-unwanted-permission-after-running-application-on-real-device

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably using a library which requests the permission. When your APK is generated, your manifest is merged with every libraries manifests.

Comment: How can I know which lib is accessing this permission?

Comment: In your module's `build/outputs/logs/` folder, you should have a manifest merger report. It should be mentioned (albeit not explicitly) here.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about this log. It is explained there. It seems that com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.4.0:24:22 is accessing this permission.

Answer (score 0):

**Requesting Permissions at Run Time**

You are facing this things(**Android OS Marsh-Mellow**), which is now required to give permission at Runtime.
[Reference Link](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)
[image]

**Permission Workflow**

In the past, the only thing that was required for developers was to check a check box in your project settings for the permissions the app needed. While this part of the app set up is the same, you must incorporate a way to request any non-normal permissions from your users and disable application functionality based on their response. I have attempted to visualize the new workflow here so you can follow along as I walk you step-by-step through determining the GPS location using my Geolocator Plugin for Xamarin.

[Reference Link](https://blog.xamarin.com/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/)

[image]

In Android 6.0 Marshmallow, application will not be granted any permission at installation time. Instead, application has to ask user for a permission one-by-one at runtime.