# Android App info show discover known accounts permission but it is not in my manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

```
<!-- Internet -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

    <!-- map -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.fg.wallet.widget.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!--shake Event-->

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

This the manifest file and after install app it shows below

[App info image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXyx7.jpg)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546197/android-studio-adds-unwanted-permission-after-running-application-on-real-device and https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/25/hey-where-did-these-permissions-come-from.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Libs can add permissions to manifest on their own. Check them too.

Comment: I use dependencies so then that libs can add permissions ?

Comment: @tharinduPro Yes, they can. Manifests from libs are merged with your's one.