# How can I override uses-feature and uses-permission

Tags: android, android-studio, android-permissions

i have following permission in my project

```
<permission
    android:name=".com.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
<uses-permission android:name=".com.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.FLASHLIGHT"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.microphone"
    android:required="false" />
```

But Google play show me some extra permission are also required then after searching I have come to know that these permission are in some of libraries am using in my project

[image]

so can any body help me to disable required permission like android.permission.CAMERA, android.permission.FLASHLIGHT and also uses-feature CAMERA, AUTOFOCUS and FLASH by overriding them in to my manifest file so that devices without flash light can also use the application.
thanks

Comment: Thanks  found solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546197/android-studio-adds-unwanted-permission-after-running-application-on-real-device?rq=1

Answer (score 12):

One of your libraries might me overriding your manifest. Try this

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" tools:replace="required" />
```