# 0 Supported devices on android playstore

Tags: android, google-developers-console, android-app-bundle

So I'm trying to upload a new version of my app to the play store, when i upload the bundle it says that my app uses 13 feature and is supported by 0 android devices.

Here are the features it uses

```
android.hardware.bluetooth, 
android.hardware.bluetooth_le,
android.hardware.camera,
android.hardware.camera.autofocus,
android.hardware.camera.flash, 
android.hardware.camera.front, 
android.hardware.camera2, 
android.hardware.faketouch, 
android.hardware.location, 
android.hardware.nfc, 
android.hardware.screen.landscape, 
android.hardware.screen.portrait, 
android.hardware.wifi
```

So I check my previous release and it had 12 features, which were the exact same as above except without the feature `android.hardware.camera2`.

I'm not sure why this feature started showing up as something my app uses, i noticed this line in my gradle file:

`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" android:required="false"/>`

So I deleted that line and rebuilt the bundle but apparently the feature is still required by my app, any ideas of how I can fix this?

Comment: Likely some library is declaring it. Check merged manifest. Also here's how to "override" that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37890351/how-can-i-override-uses-feature-and-uses-permission

Comment: @RickSanchez yes it is in the merged manifest, is there a way to see which library is putting it there?

Comment: Check the blame file under app/build/intermediates/manifest_merge_blame_file

Comment: @Michael found it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify the android:required attribute it defaults to "true". Thus, Google Play Store will assume that the application will not work without them.

Once you set android:required to false as given below, Play Store will accept the APK and will show a list of devices available for the application.

set android:required to false for the features like:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
```