# What permissions are considered collection of users' data?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, permissions, google-play-console

I have recently rolled out a simple app and it is currently still in review. When I filled out the questions I remember that I was asked whether my app collects data or not and I stated no. I am wondering if I chose the right option since I am not so sure now.

These are my permissions in my manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>
```

I also am not sure if this log code is considered collection of data which is part of my app.

```
Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial ad wasn't ready yet.");
```

and

```
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onStart");
```

These log code segments are the same ones available on the ad guide pages for android developers, I've integrated, app open ads, interstitial and banner ads. Also all the permissions are purely to allow the user to be able to see the ads so I'm not sure if this is considered collecting data. My application can work without any internet connection.

I have also made my app available to users from the ages of 6 and above as I believe that it is simple enough to use. Do I need to add in any special code that asks for permission because of this or does my app have to be made specifically for a certain age group if its below the ages of 13? I read through the policies but I don't consider that I'm collecting data or have violated any policies, or showing any type of inappropriate ads as I have disabled all these types of potential ads in my admob account for this specific ad. I'm not sure if I've done everything right or not, can someone tell me how this should be handled as I have not added any targeting code in my app. Its just the basic ad code that I have added to my app.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot determine what if you collect user data from manifest file, but depend on your manifest.

android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE is needed for accessing ConnectivityManager (mainly for monitoring network connections in general), while android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE grants access to WifiManager (for managing all aspects of Wi-Fi connectivity in particular).

In the latest release of Google Play, Google removed the need to ask permission for internet as "most apps need it anyways nowadays". However, for users who have older versions, it is still recommended to leave the code below in your manifest.

If the app doesn't contain any ads:
You can simply remove/ignore it by adding tools:node="remove" in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" tools:node="remove"/>
```

Even if another third-party library asks for this specific permission, the build will be forced not to merge it in your final Manifest file. You can get more info from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39353173/android-find-out-which-third-party-library-is-requesting-a-permission/39353246#39353246).

Also you can read about all permission from this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission).

Finally, don't worry depend on your manifest they can't be determine if you collect user data or not.