# Determine whether a permission is present in the manifest with Android 23+

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am creating a library that needs to check runtime permissions. I have got runtime permissions working fine and understand the use cases without issues.

However I would like to confirm that the developer using our library has added the permission to their manifest.

The library is a location based library and the developer can either enter `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` or `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` into the manifest and I need to be able to determine which they have used (or both) at runtime.

I though using the package manager to check permission would work however this always seems to fail:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
int granted = pm.checkPermission(
                      Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, 
                      getPackageName() );
if (granted == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
{
    // Use coarse for runtime requests
}
// granted is always PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED
```

Is there some other way to do this in Android v23+?

Comment: you can do  --- (int hasFineLocation = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        if (hasFineLocation == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {  .... )

Comment: Same thing seems to be occurring with that method as the one I've listed?

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, it wont work for Android 6.0

Comment: Ok, if you check this library (EasyPermissions)  https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions  --- this (public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {  ) creates an array with what permissions to request from the manifest. So it must be doable in API 23 by code. Dig in to the demo code to see how its done --- ha, i wrote this before you accepted the answer below :))

Comment: Thanks for that, but yeah the PackageInfo had all the information I needed, just wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Off the cuff, retrieve the `PackageInfo` via [`PackageManager` and `getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getPackageInfo(java.lang.String,%20int)). Then, look at [the `requestedPermissions` array](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#requestedPermissions) in the `PackageInfo` for all the `<uses-permission>`-requested permissions.

Comment: Ah this looks like exactly what I was after! Trying it now. Cheers

Comment: @Michael: Everything I cited has been around since API Level 1. `requestedPermissions` simply lists what was requested in the manifest and should not be affected by runtime permissions.

Comment: Cheers, have tested and is working great! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Did this really work for you? I removed the uses-permission clause from my manifest and I am still getting an entry for that permission in the requestedPermissions array. I am interested in the CAMERA_PERMISSION. I guess that does not make any difference but still...

Comment: @IkerJamardoZugaza: Perhaps [a library is adding that to your manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546197/android-studio-adds-unwanted-permission-after-running-application-on-real-device).

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to answer of [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) I'm created this method `Kotlin` to check if SMS permission is present on `Manifest`

```
fun hasSmsPermissionInManifest(context: Context): Boolean {

    val packageInfo = context.packageManager.getPackageInfo(context.packageName, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS)
    val permissions = packageInfo.requestedPermissions

    if (permissions.isNullOrEmpty())
        return false

    for (perm in permissions) {
        if (perm == Manifest.permission.READ_SMS || perm == Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS)
            return true
    }

    return false
}
```

or

```
fun Context.hasSmsPermissionInManifest(): Boolean {
    val packageInfo = packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS)
    val permissions = packageInfo.requestedPermissions

    return permissions?.any { perm -> perm == Manifest.permission.READ_SMS || perm == Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS } ?: false
}
```