# How to read manifest-declared permissions on runtime

Tags: android, permissions, android-manifest, manifest, android-permissions

I'm coding myself a simple utility library for handling runtime permission requests and I want it to throw an error every time I request a permission that is not declared in my manifest.

Is there any convenient way of checking the manifest for `uses-permission` entries without parsing it every time an activity starts?

I know there's something like `Bundle.getHeaders()` but I can't find it's documentation anywhere so I don't know how to use it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401699/determine-whether-a-permission-is-present-in-the-manifest-with-android-23/39401722#39401722 If you want, cache the results in a `static` field somewhere, since they will not change while the process is running.

Comment: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203668/how-permission-can-be-checked-at-runtime-without-throwing-securityexception> check it.