# Unwanted user-feature and user-permission upon APK release

Tags: android, google-play

I'm about to publish my APK to store and on google play and the highlighted elements were **never specified in any manifest**.

I've also decompiled the release apk and still those permissions and features are not present in the manifest.

[image: Google play]

Original manifest after merge (from build\intermediates\manifests\full\release)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<!-- Optional permission for Analytics to run. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission
    android:name="com.my.package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.my.package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Why is that and how to solve it?

**Update**

Why

```
android.hardware.location.GPS
android.hardware.screen.PORTRAIT
```

don't show up in the merged manifest?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546197/android-studio-adds-unwanted-permission-after-running-application-on-real-device

Comment: because ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and  WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE has group permissions. and GPS and READ EXTERNA STORAGE is part of it

Comment: may be these permissions used by other dependencies

Comment: @CommonsWare updated question.

Comment: The `GPS` feature is implied [due to your requesting `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions). I am not sure why whatever tool you are using is reporting `PORTRAIT`.