# Not given permission for contact still display into app permission

Tags: java, android, android-studio, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I have given this permission in my app AndroidManifest.xml file. I did't give any permission for Contacts then also it shows permission for contacts in app permission. is there any other issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546197/android-studio-adds-unwanted-permission-after-running-application-on-real-device

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android studio adds unwanted permission after running application on real device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546197/android-studio-adds-unwanted-permission-after-running-application-on-real-device)