# "Warning: Policy violation" but the apps don't require any permission

Tags: android, google-play, privacy, privacy-policy

I have developed 2 simple webapps in html+javascript for android. And today I have received 2 email from google ( 1 for each app ):

> Hello Google Play Developer,
>
> Our records show that your app, xxx, with package name
>   com.xxx.xxx.xxx, currently violates our User Data policy regarding
>   Personal and Sensitive Information.
>
> Policy issue: Google Play requires developers to provide a valid
>   privacy policy when the app requests or handles sensitive user or
>   device information. Your app requests sensitive permissions (e.g.
>   camera, microphone, accounts, contacts, or phone) or user data, but
>   does not include a valid privacy policy.
>
> Action required: Include a link to a valid privacy policy on your
>   app's Store Listing page and within your app. You can find more
>   information in our help center.
>
> Alternatively, you may opt-out of this requirement by removing any
>   requests for sensitive permissions or user data.
>
> If you have additional apps in your catalog, please make sure they are
>   compliant with our Prominent Disclosure requirements.
>
> Please resolve this issue by March 15, 2017, or administrative action
>   will be taken to limit the visibility of your app, up to and including
>   removal from the Play Store. Thanks for helping us provide a clear and
>   transparent experience for Google Play users.
>
> Regards,
>
> The Google Play Team

**These are the manifests:**

FIRST APP:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xxx.xxx.xxx" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

SECOND APP:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xxx.xxx.xxx" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And this is what the Google Play console show me in the "Store Listing" for both apps:

> Your app has an apk with version code 6 that requests the following
>   permission(s): android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS. Apps using these
>   permissions in an APK are required to have a privacy policy set.

As you can see from the manifest file, I am not requesting that permission.

So what do I have to do now ?

EDIT:

librarias used in both apps:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
```

EDIT 2:

Dependencies in the build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    wearApp project(':wear')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
}
```

Maybe play-services request that permission ?

Comment: what libraries u r using?

Comment: read `app requests or handles sensitive user or device information` .Could you share your `dependencies`

Comment: @NayanSrivastava I have added it in the question :)

Comment: [This page](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/25/hey-where-did-these-permissions-come-from.html) talks about how libraries can merge in their own permissions and suggests looking in `app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml` to see the combined ones.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546197/android-studio-adds-unwanted-permission-after-running-application-on-real-device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you're using some ad network or dependency that  request such permissions.

As an example several ad networks relies on READ_PHONE_STATE permission which could also trigger such notice from Google.

Comment: There are not ad network in the apps. How can I check if there is anything that request that permission ?

Comment: Plz ost your build.gradle dependencies section.

Comment: I have added it in the question @Andrea

Comment: The problem was 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'. I have removed it and now it doesn't require that permission