# Warnings Your Apk Is Using Permissions That Require A Privacy Policy:

Tags: android, permissions, google-play

Your app has an apk with version code 1 that requests the following permission(s): android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS. Apps using these permissions in an APK are required to have a privacy policy set.

This is the error I get on google play console, Im not asking for this permission!

Those are the only permissions my app has:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546197/android-studio-adds-unwanted-permission-after-running-application-on-real-device

Answer (score 11):

Its Bug from Google [Play Services library adding unnecessary READ_PHONE_STATE permission](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37120869)

Fixed by :

```
<manifest 
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  <!-- ... -->
>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" 
tools:node="remove" />
```

Comment: THANK YOU !!! Android play store chat people were ignorant of this bug.

Answer (score 1):

You may have used any library which uses these permissions.

Add a privacy url at the bottom of Store Listing page in Google Play to proceed.