# How to override the permission requirement from Google Play Services?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

Updated my app to use Google Play Services 12.0.

But got error while upload to Google Play. It is not me collecting phone state. And It is not reproducible on earlier version of Google Play Services.

I believe it is a **bug**.
I think a work around is to override the requirement.

**How to override the permission requirement from Google Play Services?**

> Upload failed Your APK is using permissions that require a privacy
>   policy: (android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE).

Comment: is this helpful ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/44095954/2930834

Comment: testing, hope not break anything

Comment: Your error says you need to add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission> in your Android Manifest. Did you add it?

Comment: its a bug in play services. follow Nakuls answer for the solution

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/76024034 This was part of 9.6.0 in Play Services and seems to be part of 12.0.0

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/76021774

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed it is an issue of 12.0
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/76021774

A work around will be using tools:node="remove" attribute to override the permission requirement.