# What causes the scary phone permissions statement?

Tags: android, android-permissions

I've engaged an android developer to create and publish a game app for students. The app has the following a features: 
1. a page for user to key in their their teacher's/parent's email address, so that at the completion of the game, the score is emailed to them.
2. a form by 123contact.com (a survey hosting company) which is effected by embedding a url link in the source code, which pops up a page with a survey for the user to fill up. Upon clicking the submit button, the data is automatically sent to 123contact.
On trialing the app by publishing it and downloading it, we found that before the app is installed, a permission message is displayed by Googleplay saying that the app can make a phone call without the user's consent, and the user would have to pay for the phone charges. 
What causes that and how do we get rid of the statement because it will scare users from installing the app.
Thank you

Lan

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546197/android-studio-adds-unwanted-permission-after-running-application-on-real-device

Comment: Shouldn't you be asking your developer this question?