# android requesting permission I'm not asking for

Tags: android, audio, android-manifest, record

In my android manifest I never request for the permission to allow my app to record audio however when I run my app on a Galaxy s7, there is a pop up asking for such permission.

The weird thing is this only happens when I run on an s7, if I run my app on an s6 it does not request permission to record audio.

Would anyone know why it is requesting permission to record audio when I never included it in my android manifest and why its only happening on an s7 and not an s6.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30546197/115145

Comment: The S6 is probably running Lollipop, which would explain the difference in behavior.

Comment: Post your manifest and gradle files please

Comment: thanks for sending that link CommonsWare. Helped solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app. This approach streamlines the app install process, since the user does not need to grant permissions when they install or update the app. It also gives the user more control over the app's functionality; for example, a user could choose to give a camera app access to the camera but not to the device location. The user can revoke the permissions at any time, by going to the app's Settings screen

[Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

> The weird thing is this only happens when I run on an s7, if I run my app on an s6 it does not request permission to record audio.

Basically this happens because your s7 device may have lollipop or higher android version . and s6 has lower API level (<23);

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Comment: happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to CommonsWare in the comments for posting that link, helped me solve the problem.

Basically what I did was add

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" tools:node="remove"

to my manifest file and it stopped asking for permission.