# Can't find uses-permission into manifest file

Tags: android, permissions

I'm trying to upload a new version of an application into Google Developer Console.

At the end of the upload, the console show this error message:
"Your APK uses permissions that require the setting of privacy policies: (android.permission.CAMERA)"

So I think that I have this uses-permission into the manifest file and I need to add a google privacy policy.

That's ok, but this is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="simone.biliato.delonghitrevisotvb">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name="simone.biliato.delonghitrevisotvb.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name="simone.biliato.delonghitrevisotvb.NotificationInstanceIdService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="simone.biliato.delonghitrevisotvb.NotificationMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

</application>
```

Where are all the permissions? Why I don't see them? I'm sure that I added them earlier and now disappear. Is there a specific location? A list of all permission for the project?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546197/android-studio-adds-unwanted-permission-after-running-application-on-real-device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User permissions are made up from the ones you have in your manifest and those that come from the library or dependencies you have in your project. The result will be a manifest merged by all of them. Check your dependencies.

You can use the apk analyzer : https://developer.android.com/studio/build/apk-analyzer.html

Our friends from CommonsWare give us a good solution to detect where the permissions come from: 
https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/25/hey-where-did-these-permissions-come-from.html

> To get a better sense of where those  elements are
>   coming from, we can look at
>   app/build/outputs/logs/manifest-merger-debug-report.txt.

Comment: How do I locate che correct library, that require access to CAMERA?