# React native Expo - Google Play Console tells me i ask for permissions i don't

Tags: android, react-native, google-play, expo

I'm trying to publish my React native application app to the Google Play Store, but when adding my .apk as first version, it tells me I'm asking for permissions requiring confidentiality rules, even though I never ask for those, and when installing the .apk directly on my phone, it nevers asks for any permission.

[image]

The error.

For non-french-speaking fellows, it's telling me the importation has failed because my apk uses permissions that require conficentiality rules (android.permissions.CAMERA, android.permissions.RECORD_AUDIO ...)

```
// Copyright 2015-present Facebook. All Rights Reserved.

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven'

apply plugin: 'de.undercouch.download'

import de.undercouch.gradle.tasks.download.Download
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens

// We download various C++ open-source dependencies into downloads.
// We then copy both the downloaded code and our custom makefiles and headers into third-party-ndk.
// After that we build native code from src/main/jni with module path pointing at third-party-ndk.

def downloadsDir = new File("$buildDir/downloads")
def thirdPartyNdkDir = new File("$buildDir/third-party-ndk")

// You need to have following folders in this directory:
//   - boost_1_63_0
//   - double-conversion-1.1.1
//   - folly-deprecate-dynamic-initializer
//   - glog-0.3.3
//   - jsc-headers
def dependenciesPath = System.getenv("REACT_NATIVE_DEPENDENCIES")

// The Boost library is a very large download (>100MB).
// If Boost is already present on your system, define the REACT_NATIVE_BOOST_PATH env variable
// and the build will use that.
def boostPath = dependenciesPath ?: System.getenv("REACT_NATIVE_BOOST_PATH")

task createNativeDepsDirectories {
    downloadsDir.mkdirs()
    thirdPartyNdkDir.mkdirs()
}

task downloadBoost(dependsOn: createNativeDepsDirectories, type: Download) {
    src 'https://github.com/react-native-community/boost-for-react-native/releases/download/v1.63.0-0/boost_1_63_0.tar.gz'
    onlyIfNewer true
    overwrite false
    dest new File(downloadsDir, 'boost_1_63_0.tar.gz')
}

task prepareBoost(dependsOn: boostPath ? [] : [downloadBoost], type: Copy) {
    from boostPath ?: tarTree(resources.gzip(downloadBoost.dest))
    from 'src/main/jni/third-party/boost/Android.mk'
    include 'Android.mk', 'boost_1_63_0/boost/**/*.hpp', 'boost/boost/**/*.hpp'
    includeEmptyDirs = false
    into "$thirdPartyNdkDir/boost"
    doLast {
        file("$thirdPartyNdkDir/boost/boost").renameTo("$thirdPartyNdkDir/boost/boost_1_63_0")
    }
}

task downloadDoubleConversion(dependsOn: createNativeDepsDirectories, type: Download) {
    src 'https://github.com/google/double-conversion/archive/v1.1.1.tar.gz'
    onlyIfNewer true
    overwrite false
    dest new File(downloadsDir, 'double-conversion-1.1.1.tar.gz')
}

task prepareDoubleConversion(dependsOn: dependenciesPath ? [] : [downloadDoubleConversion], type: Copy) {
    from dependenciesPath ?: tarTree(downloadDoubleConversion.dest)
    from 'src/main/jni/third-party/double-conversion/Android.mk'
    include 'double-conversion-1.1.1/src/**/*', 'Android.mk'
    filesMatching('*/src/**/*', {fname -> fname.path = "double-conversion/${fname.name}"})
    includeEmptyDirs = false
    into "$thirdPartyNdkDir/double-conversion"
}

task downloadFolly(dependsOn: createNativeDepsDirectories, type: Download) {
    src 'https://github.com/facebook/folly/archive/v2016.09.26.00.tar.gz'
    onlyIfNewer true
    overwrite false
    dest new File(downloadsDir, 'folly-2016.09.26.00.tar.gz');
}

task prepareFolly(dependsOn: dependenciesPath ? [] : [downloadFolly], type: Copy) {
    from dependenciesPath ?: tarTree(downloadFolly.dest)
    from 'src/main/jni/third-party/folly/Android.mk'
    include 'folly-2016.09.26.00/folly/**/*', 'Android.mk'
    eachFile {fname -> fname.path = (fname.path - "folly-2016.09.26.00/")}
    includeEmptyDirs = false
    into "$thirdPartyNdkDir/folly"
}

task downloadGlog(dependsOn: createNativeDepsDirectories, type: Download) {
    src 'https://github.com/google/glog/archive/v0.3.3.tar.gz'
    onlyIfNewer true
    overwrite false
    dest new File(downloadsDir, 'glog-0.3.3.tar.gz')
}

// Prepare glog sources to be compiled, this task will perform steps that normally should've been
// executed by automake. This way we can avoid dependencies on make/automake
task prepareGlog(dependsOn: dependenciesPath ? [] : [downloadGlog], type: Copy) {
    from dependenciesPath ?: tarTree(downloadGlog.dest)
    from 'src/main/jni/third-party/glog/'
    include 'glog-0.3.3/src/**/*', 'Android.mk', 'config.h'
    includeEmptyDirs = false
    filesMatching('**/*.h.in') {
        filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [
                ac_cv_have_unistd_h: '1',
                ac_cv_have_stdint_h: '1',
                ac_cv_have_systypes_h: '1',
                ac_cv_have_inttypes_h: '1',
                ac_cv_have_libgflags: '0',
                ac_google_start_namespace: 'namespace google {',
                ac_cv_have_uint16_t: '1',
                ac_cv_have_u_int16_t: '1',
                ac_cv_have___uint16: '0',
                ac_google_end_namespace: '}',
                ac_cv_have___builtin_expect: '1',
                ac_google_namespace: 'google',
                ac_cv___attribute___noinline: '__attribute__ ((noinline))',
                ac_cv___attribute___noreturn: '__attribute__ ((noreturn))',
                ac_cv___attribute___printf_4_5: '__attribute__((__format__ (__printf__, 4, 5)))'
        ])
        it.path = (it.name - '.in')
    }
    into "$thirdPartyNdkDir/glog"
}

task downloadJSCHeaders(type: Download) {
    // in sync with webkit SVN revision 174650
    def jscAPIBaseURL = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/WebKit/webkit/38b15a3ba3c1b0798f2036f7cea36ffdc096202e/Source/JavaScriptCore/API/'
    def jscHeaderFiles = ['JavaScript.h', 'JSBase.h', 'JSContextRef.h', 'JSObjectRef.h', 'JSRetainPtr.h', 'JSStringRef.h', 'JSValueRef.h', 'WebKitAvailability.h']
    def output = new File(downloadsDir, 'jsc')
    output.mkdirs()
    src(jscHeaderFiles.collect { headerName -> "$jscAPIBaseURL$headerName" })
    onlyIfNewer true
    overwrite false
    dest output
}

// Create Android.mk library module based on so files from mvn + include headers fetched from webkit.org
task prepareJSC(dependsOn: dependenciesPath ? [] : [downloadJSCHeaders]) << {
    copy {
        from zipTree(configurations.compile.fileCollection { dep -> dep.name == 'android-jsc' }.singleFile)
        from dependenciesPath ? "$dependenciesPath/jsc-headers" : {downloadJSCHeaders.dest}
        from 'src/main/jni/third-party/jsc/Android.mk'
        include 'jni/**/*.so', '*.h', 'Android.mk'
        filesMatching('*.h', { fname -> fname.path = "JavaScriptCore/${fname.path}"})
        into "$thirdPartyNdkDir/jsc";
    }
}

def getNdkBuildName() {
    if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
        return "ndk-build.cmd"
    } else {
        return "ndk-build"
    }
}

def findNdkBuildFullPath() {
    // we allow to provide full path to ndk-build tool
    if (hasProperty('ndk.command')) {
        return property('ndk.command')
    }
    // or just a path to the containing directory
    if (hasProperty('ndk.path')) {
        def ndkDir = property('ndk.path')
        return new File(ndkDir, getNdkBuildName()).getAbsolutePath()
    }
    if (System.getenv('ANDROID_NDK') != null) {
        def ndkDir = System.getenv('ANDROID_NDK')
        return new File(ndkDir, getNdkBuildName()).getAbsolutePath()
    }
    def ndkDir = android.hasProperty('plugin') ? android.plugin.ndkFolder :
            plugins.getPlugin('com.android.library').hasProperty('sdkHandler') ?
                    plugins.getPlugin('com.android.library').sdkHandler.getNdkFolder() :
                    android.ndkDirectory.absolutePath
    if (ndkDir) {
        return new File(ndkDir, getNdkBuildName()).getAbsolutePath()
    }
    return null
}

def getNdkBuildFullPath() {
    def ndkBuildFullPath = findNdkBuildFullPath()
    if (ndkBuildFullPath == null) {
        throw new GradleScriptException(
            "ndk-build binary cannot be found, check if you've set " +
            "\$ANDROID_NDK environment variable correctly or if ndk.dir is " +
            "setup in local.properties",
            null)
    }
    if (!new File(ndkBuildFullPath).canExecute()) {
        throw new GradleScriptException(
            "ndk-build binary " + ndkBuildFullPath + " doesn't exist or isn't executable.\n" +
            "Check that the \$ANDROID_NDK environment variable, or ndk.dir in local.properties, is set correctly.\n" +
            "(On Windows, make sure you escape backslashes in local.properties or use forward slashes, e.g. C:\\\\ndk or C:/ndk rather than C:\\ndk)",
            null)
    }
    return ndkBuildFullPath
}

task buildReactNdkLib(dependsOn: [prepareJSC, prepareBoost, prepareDoubleConversion, prepareFolly, prepareGlog], type: Exec) {
    inputs.file('src/main/jni/react')
    outputs.dir("$buildDir/react-ndk/all")
    commandLine getNdkBuildFullPath(),
            'NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null',
            "NDK_APPLICATION_MK=$projectDir/src/main/jni/Application.mk",
            'NDK_OUT=' + temporaryDir,
            "NDK_LIBS_OUT=$buildDir/react-ndk/all",
            "THIRD_PARTY_NDK_DIR=$buildDir/third-party-ndk",
            "REACT_COMMON_DIR=$projectDir/../ReactCommon",
            '-C', file('src/main/jni/react/jni').absolutePath,
            '--jobs', project.hasProperty("jobs") ? project.property("jobs") : Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors()
}

task cleanReactNdkLib(type: Exec) {
    commandLine getNdkBuildFullPath(),
            "NDK_APPLICATION_MK=$projectDir/src/main/jni/Application.mk",
            "THIRD_PARTY_NDK_DIR=$buildDir/third-party-ndk",
            "REACT_COMMON_DIR=$projectDir/../ReactCommon",
            '-C', file('src/main/jni/react/jni').absolutePath,
            'clean'
}

task packageReactNdkLibs(dependsOn: buildReactNdkLib, type: Copy) {
    from "$buildDir/react-ndk/all"
    exclude '**/libjsc.so'
    into "$buildDir/react-ndk/exported"
}

task packageReactNdkLibsForBuck(dependsOn: packageReactNdkLibs, type: Copy) {
    from "$buildDir/react-ndk/exported"
    into "src/main/jni/prebuilt/lib"
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        ndk {
            moduleName "reactnativejni"
        }

        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'IS_INTERNAL_BUILD', 'false'
        buildConfigField 'int', 'EXOPACKAGE_FLAGS', '0'
        testApplicationId "com.facebook.react.tests.gradle"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = []
        jniLibs.srcDir "$buildDir/react-ndk/exported"
        res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res/devsupport', 'src/main/res/shell', 'src/main/res/views/modal', 'src/main/res/views/uimanager']
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/libraries/soloader/java', 'src/main/jni/first-party/fb/jni/java']
            exclude 'com/facebook/react/processing'
            exclude 'com/facebook/react/module/processing'
        }
    }

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn packageReactNdkLibs
    }

    clean.dependsOn cleanReactNdkLib

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'src/main/third-party/java/infer-annotations/', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.fbui.textlayoutbuilder:textlayoutbuilder:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-okhttp3:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.6.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.13.0'
    compile 'org.webkit:android-jsc:r174650'

    testCompile "junit:junit:${JUNIT_VERSION}"
    testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:${POWERMOCK_VERSION}"
    testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:${POWERMOCK_VERSION}"
    testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-classloading-xstream:${POWERMOCK_VERSION}"
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:${MOCKITO_CORE_VERSION}"
    testCompile "org.easytesting:fest-assert-core:${FEST_ASSERT_CORE_VERSION}"
    testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:${ROBOLECTRIC_VERSION}"

    androidTestCompile fileTree(dir: 'src/main/third-party/java/buck-android-support/', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.3'
    androidTestCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:${MOCKITO_CORE_VERSION}"
}

apply from: 'release.gradle'
```

Comment: You might have used other libraries which use that permission. Post your build.gradle file.

Comment: I added the build.gradle file in the node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid directory, hope that's what you meant :)

Comment: <Your project>/android/app/build.gradle

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546197/android-studio-adds-unwanted-permission-after-running-application-on-real-device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My question has been answered on the Expo Forum.

In your app.json :

```
...
"android": {
    ...,
    "permissions": []
},
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just spent 3 damn hours on this crap.

If they ask you for permissions make sure you have the correct permissions in your

`src/app/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

for a full list of permission check [React-native Android permission](https://reactnative.dev/docs/permissionsandroid)

```xml
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

after you have done that (this is the part that took me 3 hours) :

1. go to your google play store
2. scroll down to the bottom
3. look at the left side for a like `app content`, click on that
4. fill in your `Privacy policy` info (they want a link for that)
5. Upload your app again
6. ENJOY!!!!