# READ_PHONE_STATE warning on google console while not declared

Tags: android, android-permissions

The title say it all, I pushed a new version on google play store and its warning me about `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission I just added (which I do not recall).

For proof here's my manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="asia.gyde.gyde">

    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:name=".application.GydeApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="725e158185a905c82a014cf6edd335657837a35c" />
        <!-- <meta-data -->
        <!-- android:name="asia.gyde.gyde.utils.GlideConfiguration" -->
        <!-- android:value="GlideModule" /> -->

        <receiver android:name=".receivers.NetworkChangeReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name=".receivers.AuthenticationManager" />
        <receiver
            android:name=".receivers.BootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name=".receivers.AppUpgraded">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name=".receivers.PowerConnectionReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.main_screens.HomeActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="reverseLandscape"
            android:theme="@style/HomeActivityStyle">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.main_screens.MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"
            android:screenOrientation="reverseLandscape"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.main_screens.VideoLoopActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="reverseLandscape"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.main_screens.VideoScreen"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="reverseLandscape"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.main_screens.IdleActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="reverseLandscape"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.main_screens.ExitActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="reverseLandscape"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.main_screens.CompanyAdsActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="reverseLandscape" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.companies.nokair_campaign.NokAirPlacePopupActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="reverseLandscape"
            android:theme="@style/MyTransparentTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.companies.nokair_campaign.NokAirPopupActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="reverseLandscape"
            android:theme="@style/MyTransparentTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.companies.starbucks_campaign.StarbucksPopupActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="reverseLandscape"
            android:theme="@style/MyTransparentTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.main_screens.DownloadActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:screenOrientation="reverseLandscape"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize" />

        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="asia.gyde.gyde"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>

        <service android:name=".application.GPSTracker" />
        <service
            android:name=".services.OnClearFromRecentService"
            android:stopWithTask="false" />

        <service
            android:name=".services.RetryBluetoothService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I'm wondering what could cause it, such as the permission being declared in a library I'm using, or asking for the permission at runtime rather than manifest (For the record I checked both and couldn't find any declaration of `READ_PHONE_STATE warning on google console` while not declared)

**EDIT** : Indeed I import way too many libraries including compile `'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.6.2'`

Unfortunately when I try to just use the libraries I need, I still get an error for a non existing resource on an XML file        `android:textColor="@color/cast_expanded_controller_progress_text_color"`

I replaced `'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.6.2'` with :

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:11.6.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.6.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.6.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-awareness:11.6.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:11.6.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.6.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:11.6.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:11.6.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.6.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.6.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.6.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:11.6.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-panorama:11.6.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:11.6.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:11.6.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:11.6.2'
```

> Note : I do not get the error with the whole bundle and get it when
>   importing every and each libraries of the bundle

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546197/android-studio-adds-unwanted-permission-after-running-application-on-real-device

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there's one library included in Google play services but never mentionned :
`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:11.6.2'`