# Still getting the warning on Google Play Store that the App will be removed even though I've removed the permissions from Android Manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest

After the update to Google Policy I've removed the permissions for `CALL_PHONE` and   `SEND_SMS` from my `AndroidManifest.xml`.

After uploading the latest version (yesterday) when I login to my Publish Dashboard, I'm still getting the warning that the application will be removed on 9th January.

These are the permissions I'm using in the Manifest now.

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

This is the warning I'm getting.

[image]

I've also noticed that if I check the Permissions used in the Google Play Listing, they are:

```
This app has access to:

Location
    approximate location (network-based)
    precise location (GPS and network-based)
Phone
    read phone status and identity

Photos/Media/Files
    read the contents of your USB storage
    modify or delete the contents of your USB storage

Storage
    read the contents of your USB storage
    modify or delete the contents of your USB storage

Wi-Fi connection information
    view Wi-Fi connections

Device ID & call information
    read phone status and identity

Phone
    directly call phone numbers
    read phone status and identity
Other
    receive data from Internet
    mock location sources for testing
    view network connections
    full network access
    prevent device from sleeping
    read Google service configuration
```

Is this due to the `READ_PHONE_STATE` Permission? or does this take some time to update?

Comment: one of the dependencies might have it listed

Comment: @TimCastelijns how can I check that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546197/android-studio-adds-unwanted-permission-after-running-application-on-real-device

Answer (score 0):

There might be some permission available in some other module or library you are using in project

Please remove manually from manifest like this

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" tools:node="remove"

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"  tools:node="remove"

hope it will help