# App not using sensitive permissions but cant release

Tags: android, permissions

I tried every thing, i deleted any apks in beta and alpha . i dont have any sensitive permissions in my app , here are my requested permissions in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

and when uploading a new release it says i'm using sensitive permissions that wasnt declared, it shows the below permissions :

3 differentiating:

```
     android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, 
     android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE,           
     com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE
```

11 common:

```
 android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, 
 android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,      
 android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, android.permission.INTERNET,      
 android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.permission.WAKE_LOCK,      
 android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, com.android.vending.BILLING,      
com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE, 
com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES,      
com.quantyam.controllcenter.Sokan.permission.C2D_MESSAGE
```

I used to have sensitive apps request like 3 releases ago and the last two times I uploaded i never had this issue

Comment: Those permissions are coming from libraries, it appears. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546197/android-studio-adds-unwanted-permission-after-running-application-on-real-device

Comment: I checked Merged manifest ( following the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/53847915/780277 ) . Still no libraries uses either Call or SMS

Comment: one additional change in this version is that i switched to Andoridx, that doesnt have an affect does it ?

Comment: It changes what libraries you are using. It does not have any direct effect upon permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I now fixed the issue , and here is how :

First go to Create release then Add from Library , then I picked up a version from my app where it uses SMS & Call permissions . then it showed me the declaration form which i filled and clicked review.

Then clicked on previous and uploaded new version and it worked perfectly