# Why am I getting SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission required warning?

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am getting below warning in play-console while releasing app, my app doesn't require any feature related to SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW then why am I getting this warning?

**targetSdkVersion 29**

It would be a great help if someone could explain this? Thanks.

[image]

**AndoirdManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.any"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />
```

Comment: i think because of some libraries you imported

Comment: @Jerson you mean it's required by any third-party library?

Comment: Please share your manifest file.

Comment: @FahadNasrullah updated the question please have a look.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30546197/115145

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the issue through the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546197/android-studio-adds-unwanted-permission-after-running-application-on-real-device) @CommonsWare mentioned in the comments above.

I have added a third party sdk which requires the SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission.

[image]

Thank you all.