# Permissions on Play Store different from Manifest file

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, google-play-console

When submitting app for Play Store kids category, it got denied because it uses location. All previous builds were accepted, but suddenly now it's no longer valid for the same build. In Play Store I see the permissions below being a part of the build, but in the Manifest file I've never requested the permissions. This is the list of Play Store permissions:

```
android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, 
android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, 
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, 
android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE, 
android.permission.INTERNET, 
android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, 
com.android.vending.BILLING
```

And my Manifest file only has these two listed:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

Any idea why is Play Store displaying more permissions than my app actually requires? Is this a bug on Play Store? This is blocking me from publishing updates, even though permissions requested are not matching the ones Play Store discovers when apk is uploaded. Could it be that some 3rd party package included in the Flutter app might require those, even though it's not listing them in the docs?

EDIT: What I did as suggested in the comments below is to add this to the manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" tools:node="remove" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" tools:node="remove"/>
```

But the error on Play console still persists.
[image]

Comment: "Could it be that some 3rd party package included in the Flutter app might require those, even though it's not listing them in the docs?" -- sure. I'm not a Flutter dev, but if you use Android Studio, the manifest editor will have a Merged Manifest sub-tab showing the overall manifest after merging in stuff from third-party libraries.

Comment: Is there a way to exclude permissions I'm 100% sure that the app is not using?

Comment: You can add `<uses-permission>` elements, naming the permissions, with `tools:node="remove"` attributes, in your manifest, to override what you get from the libraries. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/30546670/115145 for more.

Comment: I did remove the permission, but the error on the app store still looks like this "You must remove the request for location permissions from your app if your target audience only includes children under the age of 13". Looks like it's not deprecating 3rd party library manifest requirement for some reason.