# My App is asking "Microphone: record audio" permission even thought i am not using it

Tags: android, permissions, manifest

below are permission that i am using

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

there is no microphone permission in my Manifest then why playstore is asking for "MicroPhone" permission while app installation

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546197/android-studio-adds-unwanted-permission-after-running-application-on-real-device

Comment: @CommonsWare your reference work for me, i solved this by referring debug manifest , which module was using this permission. and i have added this below code so that ,playstore will not ask this permission while installing app , `<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"
        tools:node="remove" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your app module depends on some other libraries that use this permission.
It's not necessary that microphone audio permission is declared in your AndroidManifest. It can be declared in 3rd-party library.

Answer (score 2):

Although dmitriyzaitsev 's answer is right, I wanted to append it with a method for checking how you can find out which modules add which permissions. To do that, you need to go to the following file:

```
app/build/outputs/logs/manifest-merger-<app_flavor>-report.txt
```

There you can search for the permission you are interested in, e.g. RECORD_AUDIO. Your result should look something like this:

```
ADDED from [com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.2.2] /Users/jakubkomorowski/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/firebase-common-11.2.2.aar/7f3b39613ed1e03ef066f866e7495b17/AndroidManifest.xml:6:79-143
uses-permission#android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
```

You can find out more in the [google developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html#inspect_the_merged_manifest_and_find_conflicts)